# If else statements not working when getting variables from PHP to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am getting a number that is either 1 or 2 from a php site. If else statements below always return 7. I checked the var z function it works well and returns the numbers. I checked if returned values are actually seen as numbers and thats true. Tried both == and === in the statements. Tried putting '' for values after =. Nothing worked. What could be the issue?

```
var z = '<?php echo $x; ?>'; 
if (z == 1){
    q = 5;
} else if (z == 2){
    q = 6;
} else {
    q = 7;
}
```

EDIT, MORE CODE for variable £x:

```
 <?php 
                $x = (mt_rand(1,2)); ?>
                <script>
                  var z = '<?php echo $x; ?>';
                </script>
```

Comment: Here is what you can do put `console.log(z);` before if condition and put `console.log(q);` at the end of the code and show the output.

Comment: More context required, by that I mean more code. For example is this code in a `<script>` tag

Comment: I have checked your code the issue is for sure with the php returning variable. If you are using == operator try using `parseInt(z)`

Comment: I checked your code and if $x is 1 or 2 - the code works as expected. *So*, or you have more code below the condition that modifies **q** or $x isn't really 1 or 2.